# Prevent delimiter collision while reading csv in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, spark-csv

I'm trying to create an RDD using a CSV dataset.

The problem is that I have a column `location` that has a structure like `(11112,222222)` that I dont use.

So when I use the `map` function with `split(",")` its resulting in two columns.

Here is my code :

```
     val header = collisionsRDD.first 

     case class Collision (date:String,time:String,borogh:String,zip:String,
      onStreet:String,crossStreet:String,                                  
      offStreet:String,numPersInjured:Int,
      numPersKilled:Int,numPedesInjured:Int,numPedesKilled:Int,
      numCyclInjured:Int,numCycleKilled:Int,numMotoInjured:Int)   


     val collisionsPlat = collisionsRDD.filter(h => h != header).
                map(x => x.split(",").map(x => x.replace("\"","")))

     val collisionsCase = collisionsPlat.map(x => Collision(x(0),
                                x(1), x(2), x(3),                  
                                x(8), x(9), x(10),
                                x(11).toInt,x(12).toInt,
                                x(13).toInt,x(14).toInt,
                                x(15).toInt,x(16).toInt,
                                x(17).toInt))
     collisionsCase.take(5)
```

How can I catch the `,` inside this field and not consider it as a CSV delimiter?

Comment: Why on earth are you using RDD API?! Why don't you use Dataset API instead? #curious

Comment: i think because im at learning stage and dont know that much :)

Comment: So, please, since you're at learning stage, forget about RDDs and embrace Dataset API. That **will** make your life so much easier. You can always go back to RDDs **once** you grasp Dataset API.

Comment: i will do it for sure, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to read the file because it has the option `quote` enabled

For Spark 1.6 :

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databticks.spark.csv").load(file)
```

or for Spark 2 :

```
spark.read.csv(file)
```

From the Docs:

> `quote`: by default the quote character is `"`, but can be set to any character. Delimiters inside quotes are ignored

```
$ cat abc.csv
a,b,c
1,"2,3,4",5
5,"7,8,9",10

scala> case class ABC (a: String, b: String, c: String)

scala> spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("abc.csv").as[ABC].show
+---+-----+---+
|  a|    b|  c|
+---+-----+---+
|  1|2,3,4|  5|
|  5|7,8,9| 10|
+---+-----+---+
```